# Plyr + Azure media Service with DRM protection

Tags: azure, video, media, drm

I'm trying to play an Azure Media DRM-protected video in Plyr video player using the official documentation from both Plyr and Azure Media Services. However, the video keeps loading indefinitely with no error message displayed.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- I've followed the official documentation from Plyr and Azure Media Services to install and set them up.
- I've checked that both libraries are loaded correctly.
- I've implemented the Plyr and Azure Media DRM integration code as instructed.

However, I'm still unable to play the video. I've also checked the console and the network tab of my browser's developer tools, but I'm not getting any error messages.

Can anyone guide me on how to troubleshoot and fix this issue? Specifically, I would like to know:

- Are there any common issues that could cause this problem?
- Are there any specific settings or configurations I need to make to make this work?
- How can I check if the Azure Media DRM-protected video is correctly set up and loaded?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

I was expecting to be able to play Azure Media DRM-protected video in Plyr video player without any issues. However, the video keeps loading indefinitely with no error message displayed. I'm not sure what could be causing this issue, as I've followed the official documentation from Plyr and Azure Media Services carefully.

Any help or guidance on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.